# PHP Как сделать запрос без перехода на новую страницу?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

При нажатии на кнопку `Add user` запрос срабатывает и перекидывает на стр `regist.php`. Мне надо без перехода на страницу. Если я  правильно понимаю, то есть два решения. Код должен быть в `index.php` или через `AJAX`, или есть третий вариант?

index.html

```
  <form  action="regist.php" method="post" >
     <input type="text" name="First" placeholder="First Name">
     <input type="text" name="Last"  placeholder="Last Name">
     <button type="submit" name="post_user" value="Add">Add user</button>
  </form>
```

---

regist.php

---

```
if(isset($_POST['post_user'])){

   /.../

}
```

Comment: <p>можно сделать так, в конце <code>regist.php</code></p> написай так <code>header("Location: index.html");</code>

Comment: но это плохой вариант, делай ajax

Comment: делай ajax и не парься

Comment: в самый конец файла regist.php?

Comment: Понял, буду через ajax

Comment: @МишаПодлевских, А почему без перехода? Делайте редирект на ту же страницу, либо на другую после обработки данных.

Answer (score 1):

На странице можешь использовать jQuery
Если нужно отправить без перезагрузки страницы, вот тебе одно из решений:

```
$.post("regist.php", {
    first: $('input[name="First"]').val(),
    last: $('input[name="Last"]').val()
});
```

Только на кнопку повешай перехват события и вызывай этот код.
Так же у метода `$.post` есть много callback методов, например статус ответа сервера. Если есть необходимость получить ответ от сервера после отправки и что-то делать дальше.

Comment: preventDefault забыл.